# For loop is making 3600 database requests to load Products. PHP

Tags: php, magento

Problem: One piece (That we can identify currently) is causing a clients product list to call the database over and over again (3600 times) at points when loading a longer list of products.

Code:

```
<?php foreach ($cats as $cat) :
if (in_array($cat->getId(), [68, 28, 27, 59, 79, 80, 119])) :

$cat_show = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getId());
$children = $cat_show->getChildrenCategories($cat->getId());
$url1 = $cat_show->getURL();
$showAnyways = in_array(strtolower($cat_show->getName()), ["hats", "juniors", "accessories"]);

if ($cat_show->getShowSidebar() == 1 || $showAnyways) : ?>
<li class="current<?php if ($cat->getId() == $current_cat) { ?> active <?php } ?>">
    <a href="<?php echo $url1 ?>"><?php echo $cat->getName() ?></a>
    <ul>
        <?php if ($cat_show->getID() != 68 && $cat_show->getID() != 59) { ?>
            <li class="current<?php if ($cat->getId() == $current_cat && $j == 0) {
                $j++; ?> active<?php } ?>"><a class="view_all" href="<?php echo $url1 ?>"><?php echo $this->__("View All"); ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php foreach ($children as $subcat) {
            $subcat_show = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subcat->getId());
            if ($subcat_show->getShowSidebar() == 1 || in_array($subcat_show->getID(), [84])) {
                $grand_children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($subcat->getId());
                if ($grand_children) {
                    $cats_displayed = 0;
                    foreach ($grand_children as $grand_child) {
                        $grand_child_show = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($grand_child->getId());
                        if ($grand_child_show->getShowSidebar() == 1) {
                            $url = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($grand_child_show->getId())->getURL();
                            ?>
                            <li class="current<?php if ($grand_child->getId() == $current_cat && $j == 0) {
                                $j++; ?> active<?php } ?>">
                                <a href="<?php echo $url ?>"><?php echo $grand_child_show->getName() ?></a>
                            </li>
                            <?php $cats_displayed++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ($cats_displayed == 0 || !$grand_children) {
                    $url = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subcat->getId())->getURL();
                    ?>
                    <li class="current<?php if ($subcat->getId() == $current_cat && $j == 0) {
                        $j++; ?> active<?php } ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo $url ?>"><?php echo $subcat->getName() ?></a>
                    </li>
                <?php }
            }
        } ?>
    </ul>
</li>
<?php endif;?>
<?php endif;?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Can anyone provide me with some pointers on how to make this FAR more efficient and not make so many DB calls.

Should note, I am not an amazing php developer by trade. Main language is python so I am trying to get some advice on the best way to go about fixing this given my less that great knowledge of php itself.

Answer (score 1):

You should never have a database query call inside a for loop. You need to build a query at the start that will get all the data required before the for loop.

Some instant pointers I can see are:

```
$grand_child_show = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($grand_child->getId());
                        if ($grand_child_show->getShowSidebar() == 1) {
                            $url = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($grand_child_show->getId())->getURL();
```

This is calling the database twice for no reason, you should be able to do this:

```
 $grand_child_show = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($grand_child->getId());
                            if ($grand_child_show->getShowSidebar() == 1) {
                                $grand_child_show->getURL();
```

You should be able to drop all these 'GetModel' functions if at the start of the script you call something like:

```
$all_grand_children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getAllCategories();
```

This would return a hash array which you would be able to access relevant items by doing the following inside the for loop:

```
$grand_children = $all_grand_children[$subcat->getId()];
```

This would replace

```
$grand_children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($subcat->getId());
```

You should also do a initial call for all of the grand_child and cat_show objects. If you are skilled at SQL you can call just the relevant information by joining the tables in one SQL query.

Comment: No worries! Let me know if you have any trouble with this!

Comment: I absolutely will! Thank you again!

Comment: @jodran121sa Could you show me how you would go about the implementation of this if possible?